# If every linear equation of a system is a linear combination of another system and vice-versa, then both systems have the same solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I'm working on Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra* and encountered this theorem but without proof. I know it might seem trivial to some of you, but as I'm a first-year, I'd like to practice my proof-writing skills. Could you review this proof, please?

**Lemma**. For every linear equation $j$ with solution set $F$ and system of linear equation $A x = b$ with solution set $G$, where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix of coefficients, $x$ is an $n \times 1$ vector of unknowns and $b$ is an $m \times 1$ vector of values, if $j$ is a linear combination of $A x = b$, then $G$ is a subset of $F$.

*Proof*. Suppose $j$ is a linear combination of $Ax = b$. Then for some $1 \times m$ vector $c$, $j$ is $cAx = cb$. By equality, for every $x$, if $A x = b$, then $cAx = cb$. That is, by subset definition, $G$ is a subset of $F$. Q.E.D.

**Theorem**. For every systems of linear equations $R$ and $S$ with respectively solution sets $U$ and $V$, and arbitrary linear equations $r$ and $s$, if $r$ is a linear combination of $s$ and $s$ is a linear combination of $r$, then $U = V$.

*Proof*. Suppose $r$ is a linear combination of $s$. Then by Lemma, $V$ is a subset of $U$.
Suppose $s$ is a linear combination of $r$. Then by Lemma, $U$ is a subset of $V$. By set equality definition, $U = V$. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

The lemma and its proof are correct. The statement of the theorem can be improved. For instance, you want to say that $r$ and $s$ are arbitrary linear equations *in the systems $R$ and $S$ respectively*. Also, you want to say, "If $r$ is a linear combination of $S$ and $s$ is a linear combination of $R$, then $U = V$."

The proof of the theorem also needs a few more ingredients. Here is one way to complete it.

*Proof.* Suppose $r$ is a linear combination of $S$. Then by Lemma, $V$ is a subset of the set of solutions of $r$, say $F_r$. Since $r$ was an arbitrary linear equation in the system $R$, $V \subseteq \bigcap_{r \in R} F_r = U$. Repeating the argument the other way around, we get $U \subseteq V$. Hence, $U = V$.

---

Just to make a note, this theorem is actually proved by Hoffman and Kunze. The informal discussion (on page 4, 2nd edition) before the statement of Theorem 1 actually constitutes a proof.